# How do i architect this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model **Store** with attributes **user_id, product_id** and **token_string**.

In the form I collect values for **user_id**  and **product_id** but not **token_string** because it is going to be generated after user_id and product_id are saved.
So in the create action the **@store** is saved normally with only two attributes values and **nil** token_string.

But right after **@store** is saved i want to generate a random token_string(doesn't matter how) and save it to the database on the same row as **product_id** and **user_id** where there is **nil**(i am not sure if update_attribute would do).But the biggest challenge is there is a number from a variable i have to multiply to token generation.

So lets say the number is **2**
That means i would generate two **token_strings** and both have to be saved to the same **user_id** and **product_id**.How do i go around this?

Thank you in advance

```
    def create
      @quantity=2
      @store=Store.new(params[:store])

      if @store.save
         @quantity.times{ generate token string}
         #Then save both generated tokens to the same user_id and product_id
        redirect_to :controller=>"products",:action=>"index"
      else
        redirect_to :action=>"new"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to save token_string in the same record

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :token_generate

  private

  def token_generate
    self.token_string = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user_id + token_id + Time.now)
  end

end
```

but if you need to duplicate the @store with the same **user_id** and **product_id** that method can be helpful

```
# model
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  def duplicate_with_token!(quantity)
    1.upto(quantity) do
      obj = self.clone
      obj.token_string = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user_id + token_id + Time.now)
      obj.save
    end
  end
end

# controller
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @store=Store.new(params[:store])
    if @store.save
      @store.duplicate_with_token!(2)
      #Then save both generated tokens to the same user_id and product_id
      redirect_to "products#index"
    else
      redirect_to :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how do i save all of them to the same user_id/product_id,and lastly how would i access the quantity in the controller, from Active record class?

Comment: Thank you ,that is very helpful ,did you mean product_id where it says token_id?

Comment: *user_id* and *token_id* are taken from the saved **@store**, so you will run **@store.save; @store.duplicate_with_token(2)**

Comment: token will be different, because it depends on *Time.now*

Comment: would i be able to retrieve later those generated token string based on product_id?Because the relationship is **Product** has_many **stores**.

Comment: each of token are going to be saved in DB per each store, you can retrieve it then

Answer (score 0):

You can update the field after save. is there any other complication or scenario is present?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to update an attribute of your Stores model after you save it? So after saving, use update_attribute:

```
#Then save both generated tokens to the same user_id and product_id
@store.update_attribute('token_string', @quantity.times{ generate token string})
```

I am assuming that your code sample above is in your controller and for some reason user_id and product_id will only be available after your save given your explanation.

Your "generate token string" pseudo code would use @store.user_id and/or @store.product_id in what ever algorithm you require. Meaning that their values are now set since you have saved it, it is updated with those new values.